# R: Append row as moving average growth rate

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a few columns and I would like to append a row to the bottom of this dataframe which contains the moving average of the growth rates for the last 2 rows of data in each column.

Data:

```
A | B
3 | 4
4 | 3
5 | 5
4 | 3
1 | 5
```

New row for column `A`, `((1-4)/4 + (4-5)/5)/2 = -0.475` and `B`, `2/15`.

So the dataframe would like:

```
A      |   B
3      |   4
4      |   3
5      |   5
4      |   3
1      |   5
-0.475    0.133
```

I have tried the below but unfortunately it isn't working I can't find a way to use the last calculation for each column to use as the new row. How should I go about this?

```
moving_avg_growth_rate = function (x) {
  growth = x/lag(x) - 1
  moving_average = filter(growth, rep(1/2, 2))
  return (moving_average)
}

lapply(dataframe, moving_avg_growth_rate)
```

Comment: calculate the growth rate separately and then `rbind`it to the original df

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some possibilities:

**1) code in question modified** `lag` is for time series.  Also use tail to get the last moving avg:

```
moving_avg_growth_rate = function (x) {
  growth = x[-1]/x[-length(x)] - 1
  moving_average = filter(growth, rep(1/2, 2), sides = 1)
  tail(moving_average, 1)
}
rbind(dataframe, lapply(dataframe, moving_avg_growth_rate))
```

**1a)** Note that since we really only need the last moving average we could use

```
moving_avg_growth_rate2 <- function(x) {
   xx <- tail(x, 3)
   mean(xx[-1] / xx[-3] - 1)
}
rbind(dataframe, lapply(dataframe, moving_avg_growth_rate2))
```

**2) shorter**

```
Tail <- tail(dataframe, 3)
rbind(dataframe, colMeans(Tail[-1, ] / Tail[-3, ] - 1))
```

**Note:** The input data in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "
A      |   B
3      |   4
4      |   3
5      |   5
4      |   3
1      |   5"
dataframe <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, sep = "|")
```